# SQL: group employees inside a row

Tags: mysql, sql

I guess, this is a simple one.
Let's say, I have two tables: [employees] and [projects]

```
SELECT p.project_name, concat(e.first_name, " ", e.last_name) as employee_name
    FROM project p
    INNER JOIN employee e on e.project_id = p.id
    ORDER by p.project_name
```

With that SELECT I get

```
JohnJane Project | John Doe 
JohnJane Project | Jane Doe
T Project        | Mr. T
```

But instead I would like to have the names comma-separated in a row:

```
 JohnJane Project | John Doe, Jane Doe
  T Project | Mr. T
```

How can I do that?

Thanks
Bernhard

Comment: GROUP BY combined with MySQL's GROUP_CONCAT?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Group by the project and use `GROUP_CONCAT`

```
SELECT p.project_name, 
       group_concat(concat(e.first_name, " ", e.last_name)) as employee_name
FROM project p
INNER JOIN employee e on e.project_id = p.id
GROUP BY p.project_name
ORDER by p.project_name
```

Comment: Holy cow. You're damn fast!
Thanks, that was it.